# Show that stochastic integral w.r.t. Brownian motion is normal distributed

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, characteristic-functions

I want to show the following claim:

Let $B$ be a one-dimensional Brownian motion and let $$I(\phi):=\int_0^1 \phi(s) \text{d}B_s.$$
Show that $\mathbb{E}(I(\phi))=0$ and $\mathbb{V}(I(\phi))=\int_0^1(\phi(s))^2\text{d}s$.

I want to use characteristic functions to prove this.

I already showed that $$\int_0^1 \phi(s) \text{d}B_s  = -\int_0^1 B_s(\omega) \text{d}\phi(s),$$
where the right hand integral is constructed as a Riemann-Stieltjes integral:$$\int_0^1B_s(\omega) \text{d}\phi(s) = \lim_\limits{|\mathscr{P}|\rightarrow 0} \sum_{[u,v) \in \mathscr{P}} B_{\xi(u,v)}(\omega)\phi_{u,v}.$$

So, $$\mathbb{E}\exp(itI(\phi))= \mathbb{E}\exp \bigg[-it \big(\lim_\limits{|\mathscr{P}|\rightarrow 0} \sum_{[u,v) \in \mathscr{P}} B_{\xi(u,v)}(\omega)\phi_{u,v} \big) \bigg].$$

Next step will probably be to prove that the limit can be taken out of the expectation but how do I proceed from then on? Additionally, I know that the summands are Gaussian and hence the sum is again gaussian.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Limit can be taken out by DCT. After doing this write down the characteristic function explicitly and you will get the answer.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Ok, so since $B$ is a gaussian process, we can conclude that $\sum_{[u,v) \in \mathscr{P}} B_{\xi(u,v)}(\omega)\phi_{u,v}$ is normal distributed with mean 0 and variance $\sum_{[u,v) \in \mathscr{P}} \xi(u,v)\phi_{u,v}^2$. Is that correct? And then we should get the answer by taking the limit...